# How does importing maven dependencies impact plugin management?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Maven allows one to [import dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies), for example importing Spring Boot dependencies, into a project that has a different parent using import scope. How does this impact plugin management?

I want to use the plugin versions defined in the `<pluginManagement>` section of the imported dependency (`<spring-boot-dependencies>` in this case), but I notice different versions of plugins, like surefire, used in different environments, like on TeamCity and locally.

Answer (score 27):

With maven you can only inherit `pluginManagement` when using that POM as a parent.
Scope `import` only brings you `dependencyManagement`.

There is a ticket on the maven issue tracker though : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5588

Comment: This ticket has been created on 13/Feb/14 and updated on 08/Mar/19, but it remains open to this day despite being categorizes as 'major'...

Comment: Thanks! This bit me as well, when transitioning to a parent bom we swapped the current parent with a dependencyManagement import... which does not include the plugins.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Spring Boot docs, when [Using Spring Boot without the parent POM](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent), *you can still keep the benefit of the dependency management **(but not the plugin management)**.*